# C# SQL How do i make users only see their details in datagridview when logged on

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I'm currently developing a windows form application in visual studio 2012 which has two different logins based off whether the user is a client or admin. The Picture belows shows the login table for the sql database.

[image: Picture of image]

As you can see this is a very simple login system that has 3 columns which are Username, password and role (which determines whether a user is admin or client). 
The problem i have is that i want to create a form that allows users whose role is a client to view their own username and password information from the login table  through the use of a datagridview.

At the moment i have a button which will display all the information of every user from the login table in datagridview, how do i edit my code so that the datagridview only shows the login table details of the current logged in user? instead of displaying the login details of all users like it is now.

Here is an image of the datagrid view and view button.

[image: Basic concept image of datagridview and view button]

Below is the code for the datagridview and view button.

```
{ public ClientAnalyzeyourowninformation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this is the code for the view button of admin menu
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Login", con);
        DataTable DATA = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(DATA);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DATA;
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: You should look into a `WHERE` clause...  Additionally, you should *never* store passwords in plain text.

Comment: so many things wrong with this I'm crying tears of blood.  .NET has built in authentication and roles libraries -- please just use one of those.

Comment: you can simply add a field to the records with their user Id and then pull that information based on user Id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Membership/Roles from .NET 2.0:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is the code for the view button of admin menu
    List<MembershipUser> Users;
    if (Roles.IsInRole("Admin"))
      Users=Membership.GetAllUsers();
    else
      Users=new List<MembershipUser>() {Membership.GetUser()};
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Users;
}
```

If you insist on rolling your own:

```
con.Open();
var sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username=@Username",con);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", lblUserName.Text);
DataSet DATA = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(DATA);
dataGridView1.DataSource = DATA;
con.Close();
```

Comment: Here is a small article on how to configure, and some implementation hints: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3855.how-to-use-a-membership-provider-of-asp-net-in-winform-application.aspx

Comment: You can also use [SimpleMembership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider(v=vs.111).aspx), [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) or any of the other security packages that are much more likely to do it right.

Comment: This is a much better way then the way i'm currently doing but i can't use your way as i already have the login system done and do not want to rewrite the code again with your method. I basically just need a simple way to display only logged in details with the user that is currently logged in, i don't really care how basic it is.

Comment: If i was building an actual system for a company i would do it your way but i'm only experimenting with this specific way just to see how it would work. Thanks for your answer it definitely deserves to be voted the best, if i build an actual system for a company I will look at using simplemembership right away.

Answer (score -2):

Store username into a level when you put data for login.

```
lblUserName.Text=txtUserName.Text;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0 AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username='"+lblUserName.Text+"'", con);
    DataSet DATA = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(DATA);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DATA;
    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: Please type `' or ''='` into your username box and watch it dump all records.  I wish I could downvote this answer 1000 times.  You've just made it possible for ANY user to get the usernames and passwords of everyone in your entire system.  Congrats.